# Leading spaces are ignored (docx4j)

Tags: docx4j

I am using docx4j to load a template, replace specific keywords inside it (load the template, marshall then unmarshall)

My problem is that leading spaces inside the text I insert inside the template are ignored when I open the generated file.

I found some examples suggest to using "xml:space="preserve", but since I am using a template and xml marshall\unmarshall method to generate my report I don't know If there are a way to add this property

So, is there any way to make my reports recognize leading spaces?

Comment: ok to do this you need to replace space " " in your string with:           </w:t><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t><w:t>

Comment: or better, post-process the JAXB representation of the part, adding @xml:space to any w:t which starts or ends with white space.